# Запрос к geocoder yandex

Tags: javascript

Подкажите, пытаюсь использовать геокодер от яндекса.
Помимо этого на этом апикее я использую яндекс suggest, то есть он рабочий
но мне почему то выдает ошибку 403 'В запросе используется невалидный API-ключ'
В чем проблема?

https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params.html

```
const url = `https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=688efe04-e23e-42f4-98a7-b8cea7d40838&geocode=Москва, улица Новый Арбат, дом 24`
const request1 = await fetch(url)
console.log(request1)
```

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=688efe04-e23e-42f4-98a7-b8cea7d40838&geocode=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82,%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%2024"
```

Comment: Что за непонятные %20%20 в конце apikey

Comment: @andreymal они только в ответе, в запросе их нет

Comment: Так, может, на самом деле и в запросе есть, просто вы их не заметили? %20 это символ пробела

Comment: ...а в вашей правке `const url` зачем-то вообще в две строки записан, и символ переноса строки является частью apikey

Comment: Да, проблема действительно была в пробеле, я ее поправил, приходит код 200, но тела ответа почему то все равно нет

Comment: Логично что `await request1.json()`

Comment: @andreymal ```await request1.json()``` возвращает ```Promise {<pending>}```. В запросе согласно документации я уже указываю ```format=json```

Comment: await не может возвращать промис. Если вы не знаете, как работать с промисами и async/await, то почитайте учебник по javascript

Comment: @andreymal решено, не заметил, Спасибо! только одного не понял, зачем по документации тогда яндекс предлагает в запрос вставлять ```format=json```